Unsupported Gulp Version. for Gulp 5.0.0
I have created a Craft 4 project and I am installing Gulp on my project. I have installed he latest version of Gulp(Gulp 5) and the moment I run the gulp command, i Get this:
.
I have tried Gulp 4 as well, but I keep receiving any security vulnerabilities when I do that.
Can someone help me out?
I have tried Gulp 4 as well, but I keep receiving any security vulnerabilities when I do that.
Can someone help me out?

I updated to 5.0.0 and saw the same result. Rolled back to 4.0.2, which I had been using,  and it worked as before. It has only been out for about a week, so perhaps a bit of patience for a better error message. However, in a different directory, run gulp. Mine runs and gulp -v gives me that the CLI version is 2.3.0. I suspect that it's the global CLI version conflicting with the local directory version.

Hi @manroop-singh-nanda if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

The local-directory gulp and the globally-installed gulp are mismatched. If you gulp -v in some other directory you'll probably get 2.3.0, which is now (early 2024) outdated. Looks like gulp CLI 3.0.0 matches up with gulp 5.0.0
Uninstall/reinstall the global version, from your home directory or other directory:
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm install -g gulp

Now install gulp in your project directory, and gulp 5.0.0 should work.
I can say a more helpful error message would be nice.

Weirdly, I ran npm uninstall -g gulp-cli, then gulp -v, then npm uninstall -g gulp, then gulp -v, but both times the version still says CLI version: 2.3.0. I think npm install gulp-cli -g --force was necessary for me.

You can try
npx gulp -v this should display the version of gulp you are using.
I had gulp-cli v2.3.0 installed and that was the cause.
